# The Principle of inclusion and exclusion to find probability

Tags: probability, inclusion-exclusion, card-games

A 5-card hard is dealt from a standard deck of 52 cards. Find the Probability of at least 1 heart and 1 spade is among the 5 cards, Using Inclusion and exclusion.
So far I have 52C5-2*47C5 (47C5 from the ways to have no spades and no hearts) but from here I am in desperate need of help.

Comment: First, where did $47$ come from?  $52-13=39\neq 47$.  Next, you got the total number of hands, you subtracted the hands which had no hearts and then you subtracted the hands which had no spades.  Now you still need to add back the number of hands which simultaneously had no hearts *and* no spades.

Answer (score 2):

I see that you are trying to count selections with at least 1 from 13 hearts and at least 1 from 13 spades, by counting the complement for obtaining no hearts *or* no spades. However, you should be using the *Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion*. Also your card counts were a little off.

Here's the correction.

$$\def\ch#1#2{{^{#1}\mathrm C_{#2}}}\begin{align}\nu(N_\heartsuit{\geqslant}1\cap N_\spadesuit{\geqslant}1)=& \nu(\Omega)-\nu(N_\heartsuit{=}0\cup N_\spadesuit{=}0)\\[2ex]=&~\nu(\Omega)-\nu(N_\heartsuit{=}0)-\nu(N_\spadesuit{=}0)+\nu(N_{\heartsuit}{=}0\cap N_\spadesuit{=}0)
\\[2ex]=&~\ch{52}{5}-2\cdot\ch{(52-13)}{5}+\ch{(52-13\cdot 2)}5\\[2ex]=&~\ch{52}5 -2 \cdot\ch{39}5+\ch{26}5\end{align}$$